# Wifi Hotspot not working

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I am having Lenovo z50 70 laptop. I tried to make my laptop as a wifi hotpost using softwares - Connectify, MyPublicWifi etc and even using windows command line operation (netsh wlan..). I was successfull in creating the hotspot (as it says). But nor my phone or any of the laptops could connect to the hotspot. What can be the possible reasons?..I tried it in Windows 8 an 8.1. I made sure that that all my drivers are installed. NOTE : I am able to connect to other wireless networks with my laptop

Comment: HostedNetwork has a requirement that the wireless driver be  "Certified for Windows 7" or "Certified for Windows 8", [About the Wireless Hosted Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd815243%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @AEonAX : Mine is wireless adapter from BroadCom

Answer (score 0):

I *really* don't like the look of [their](http://www.mypublicwifi.com/publicwifi/en/index.html) page. The creator(s) of MyPublicWiFi may not have built their product well (for example, not including a integrated DHCP server?), and incorrect grammer almost always sets off  my alarms. (for example; "you virtual WIFI-Hotspot"). Try looking around for another solution before going too much further.

If you really can trust them and you think they forgot something in their product, read below.

As mentioned above, **it could be possible that there isn't a DHCP server built into MyPublicWiFi**. You can confirm this by bypassing DHCP and using a static IP. 

On  Android:

Open Settings, go to WiFi/Wireless (or WLAN on some versions), navigate to the WiFi Network List, press-and-hold on your network, and press "Modify Network".  Enable Advanced Options, scroll down to IP Settings, set the value under it to Static, and scroll down to IP Address, and set it to the specifics of your WiFi network (e.g, 192.168.137.214, as displayed on their page). Android may auto-fill the other values for you, but if not, set Gateway to 192.168.137.1
You may have to play around with this value (last digit) to get it to work. Set DNS 1 to whatever DNS server you use (for testing, 8.8.8.8, which is Google's public DNS server). Hit Save and attempt to connect again.

On IPhone, I have never used an IPhone/IPad, so research that :(

On Windows (don't care what version):
Open Control Panel, navigate to Network & Sharing Center (usually under Network & Internet), click "Change Adapter settings", right-click Wi-Fi (may be different depending on conditions), and click Properties. Don't forget UAC :((
Click on Internet Protocol Version 4 (aka ipv4), and click the Properties button below it. The setup is a bit similar to Android, although set the Subnet Mask to something like 255.255.255.0 or 255.255.255.255. Hit Ok, close the dialog behind it, all the usual stuff. Now attempt to connect to the hotspot/WiFi network.

Hope this helps :) (if a little complicated)